# Javafx выполнить код по нажатию Enter

Tags: java, javafx

У меня появился еще один вопросик, как выполнить вот этот код по нажатию клавиши Enter?

```
     public void buttonAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    String message = sendTextfield.getText();
    Random rand = new Random();

if (message != "") {
        getTextarea.appendText("Вы: "+message+"\n");
        sendTextfield.clear();
    }

    if (message.toLowerCase().contains("привет") ||
            message.toLowerCase().contains("здравствуйте") {
        String[] cats = {"Привет!", "Привет, дорогой друг!", "Здравствуйте, человек!"};

        new java.util.Timer().schedule(
                new java.util.TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getTextarea.appendText(cats[rand.nextInt(cats.length)]+"\n");
                    }
                },
                700
        );
    }
}
```

Он у меня выполняется по нажатию кнопки "Отправить", что не очень удобно.

Comment: вам нужно на кнопку повесить EventListener  и внутри обработайте нажатие на Enter

Answer (score 1):

полагаю у вас TextArea, раз кнопка называется getTextarea.

```
getTextarea.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER)  {
            String text = getTextarea.getText();

            // тут что-то делаем. Например, то, что вы указали в вопросе

            // можно в конце почистить текст
            getTextarea.setText("");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: У меня все KeyEvent'ы красным загорелись, что-то импортировать надо еще?

Comment: конечно! все современные среды разработки подскажут вам, что нужно импортировать `javafx.scene.input`

Comment: вставлял Ваш код между строчками `Random rand = new Random();` и `if (message.toLowerCase().contains...`, заработало, но только все же после нажатия кнопки "Отправить" и теперь в textarea не показываются мои сообщения

Comment: getTextarea.setText("") очищает и поэтому не показывает